# Inequality of binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-theorem

Let $n$ be a natural number.
we need to proove that:
$$\forall{1\leq k\leq\tfrac{n}2}, \text{we have } {n \choose k-1} < {n \choose k} $$

I tried to do the following with induction:

We set $n$ as a constant and doing induction on $k$:
if $ k=1 $:
${n \choose 1} > {n \choose 0}$ and it can be shown by writing the exlpicit ration of the ${i\choose j} sign $ .
Assuming that for every $k$ as it was set, the equation above is right, we will try to proove with induction that for $k+1$ we get:
$$\forall{1\leq k+1\leq\tfrac{n}{2}}, \text{we have}{n\choose k} < {n \choose k+1}$$

But at this point, I am stuck, because I can't see how can I apply the induction assumption.

I also tried to use pascal identity but I can't see how it fits in.

Comment: You should show what you have done with induction.

Comment: yes, you are right. I had just updated that one. I managed to proove the (example) base case but I am stuck in the Induction step itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving If $k \le \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ then $\binom{n}{k-1} < \binom{n}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951735/proving-if-k-le-left-lfloor-fracn2-right-rfloor-then-binomnk-1)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/857553.

Answer (score 3):

We want to show that

$\binom{n}{k-1}<\binom{n}{k}$ for all $1\leq k\leq n/2$.

With a direct calculation, we get:

$\binom{n}{k-1}=\frac{n!}{(n-k+1)!(k-1)!}\stackrel{?}{<}\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\binom{n}{k}$

We can cancel $n!$ and the inequality in question is equivalent to

$(n-k+1)!(k-1)!>(n-k)!k!$

Dividing $(n-k)!$ and $(k-1)!$, we get $n-k+1>k\Leftrightarrow n+1>2k$, as $k\leq n/2$

we have $n+1>n=2\cdot \frac{n}2\geq 2k$.