# Proof (by induction?) of binomial inequality - help needed

Tags: analysis, inequality, induction

Prove that for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\ge 2$, and for every $1\le i\le\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor$:
$$\binom{n}{i-1} < \binom{n}{i}$$
This is a homework problem and I suppose proof should be done by induction.
I'm not quite sure what to do with this $i$ because it is not fixed.

Comment: If not by induction, you may represent the two sides as $\dfrac{n!}{(i-1)!(n-i+1)!}$ and $\dfrac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$, then compare.

Comment: The definition of $i$ means

$$i \le \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor \le\frac n2 < \frac{n+1}2$$

Comment: Omg, is it really so simple?! I need some sleep, obviously. Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving If $k \le \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor$ then $\binom{n}{k-1} &lt; \binom{n}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951735/proving-if-k-le-left-lfloor-fracn2-right-rfloor-then-binomnk-1) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi-1%7D%5Clt%20%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bi%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%241%5Cle%20i%5Cle%5Clfloor%7B%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7B2%7D%7D%5Crfloor%24&p=1).

Comment: @ScientixBulgaria Welcome to Math SE. FYI, other very similar questions found include [Binomial Coefficients Inequality 3](/q/2458649), [Combinatorial proof that central binomial coefficients are the largest ones](/q/2496836), etc.